# Smoothing lines in an image?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have an image like this - 
I would like to smoothen the lines in this (as you can see they lines are a little jaggy.) How can I do this? 
[image]

I obtained the lines by isolating them from another image using a mask to threshold a colour.

```py
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
sens = 20

lower_green = np.array([60 - sens, 100, 100])
upper_green = np.array([60 + sens, 255, 255])
mask = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower_green, upper_green)

output_img = img.copy()
output_img[np.where(mask == 0)] = 0
output_hsv = img_hsv.copy()
output_hsv[np.where(mask == 0)] = 0
bit_not = cv2.bitwise_not(output_hsv)
```

This is the smoothness of line I am trying to achieve, I did this by using a line detector and redrawing the lines with the `cv2.LINE_AA` flag. But it detects the edges of the line so I get double lines which is not what I want.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried dilation: https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html

Comment: Yes, it did not help much, it helped getting some more definition to the lines but it's not very smooth

Comment: What about a gaussian blur before adding the line to the image?

Comment: What do you mean by before adding the line to the image?

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought this image was an aggregate of other sources. I see that you masked the original image to produce these lines. Apologies. But have you tried a gaussian blur?

Comment: Gaussian blur before thresholding?

Comment: Maybe, I don't know what your original image is like so I can't say what it would do

Comment: Doing some preprocessing before isolating those lines may help